# Concern with startsWith and multiple patterns in R

Tags: r, startswith

I noticed a problem or a concern with the `startsWith()` function.
The following code displays two different selection.
The first one behave normally which is this chunk of code:

```
dt_test <- data.table(a = c("abcd", "poo", "abla", "ba"),
                      id = c(1,2,3, 4))

dt_test[startsWith(a, c("ab", "ao")),id]
# [1] 1 3

startsWith(dt_test$a, c("ab", "ao"))
# TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

And if you noticed, this one only selects the first one which is counter intuitive since `id` 2 and 4 are supposed to be `TRUE`

```
dt_test <- data.table(a = c("ab","abcd", "poo", "abla", "ba"),
                      id = c(1,2,3, 4,5))

dt_test[startsWith(a, c("ab", "ao")),id]
# [1] 1

startsWith(dt_test$a, c("ab", "ao"))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What I'm I supposed to use as a substitute to `startsWith()` in this precise case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass either multiple `startsWith`

```
library(data.table)
dt_test[Reduce(`|`, lapply(c('ab', 'ao'), startsWith, x = a))]
#     a id
#1:   ab  1
#2: abcd  2
#3: abla  4
```

---

or simply use `grepl`

```
dt_test[grepl('^a[bo]', a)]
#      a id
#1:   ab  1
#2: abcd  2
#3: abla  4
```

---

Or with `%like%`

```
dt_test[a %like% '^a[bo]']
#      a id
#1:   ab  1
#2: abcd  2
#3: abla  4
```

Answer (score 2):

The `?startsWith()` help page indicates

> prefix, suffix:    character vector (often of length one).

In your case, you are passing more than one character. Therefore, multiple patterns are not allowed within `startsWith`.

You may try this:

```
dt_test[grepl('^ab|^ao', a)]
```