# mutate a new column using dplyr with values based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with multiple columns in which I want to create a new column with values based on the column `status`.

I'm new in R, but I think it would be possible to do this.

My str() of the dataframe is:
[str()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YThUU.png)
My column `status` contains a fault code with values like 240:12, 05:03: 90:312 etc. But some codes are not fault codes, just information. So I want to create a new column which states which code is a fault and which not.

I know that codes starting with: "00","01","02","03","04","05","07","08","09","10","11","12","14","15","16","17","20","21","60","240","600" are not a fault, the others are a fault code.

The values in `Status` are `character`.

My solution would be:

```r
dataframe3 %>% 
mutate(Status_fault = case_when(startsWith(Status,C("00","01","02",
                "03","04","05","07","08","09","10","11",
                "12","14","15","16","17","20","21","60","240","600"))
       ~ "No fault",
        T ~ "fault"))
```

But this results in

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Status_problem`. x object not interpretable as a factor i Input `Status_problem` is `case_when(...)`.

Anyone an idea to solve this?
I have searched on stack overflow everywhere but am looking for so long, I have the feeling I can't think straight anymore...

The question was associated with another question using lapply.
So I made a new solution:

```r
dataframe3 %>% 
 mutate(Status_problem = case_when(lapply(c('00','01','02','03','04','05','07','08','09','10','11','12','14','15','16','17','20','21','60','240','600'),starts_with, X = Status)
       ~ "No fault",
        T ~ "fault"))
```

Unfortunately this results in:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Status_problem`. x c("'c("00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "07", "08", "09", "10", ' is not a function, character or symbol", "' "11", "12", "14", "15", "16", "17", "20", "21", "60", "240", ' is not a function, character or symbol", "' "600")' is not a function, character or symbol") i Input `Status_problem` is `case_when(...)`.

Anyone sees what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I guess this should solve your issue, since you can't pass your patterns to the `startsWith` function like you do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088740/concern-with-startswith-and-multiple-patterns-in-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concern with startsWith and multiple patterns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088740/concern-with-startswith-and-multiple-patterns-in-r)

Comment: I just added some new information to the question. I've tried lapply but it does not work. I'm probably overlooking something very simple but I just don't see it....

Comment: Hi @Jan, sorry it took me so long to find your edit. You've got 3 problems with your new solution. 1) The function is called `startsWith`, not `starts_with`. 2) The first argument is `x =` not `X =`. 3) You need to wrap the `lapply` call in ```Reduce(`|`, )``` as demonstrated in the duplicate target.